# Why is reference template argument not deducing const?

Tags: c++, templates, reference, type-deduction

I have written following code and for pointer it is showing correct argument type, but when I use reference it is only showing `int` and no `const`. why?

```
template <typename T>
void increment(T& x)
{
    std::cout << "Argument type is : " << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
    //x = x + 1;
}

template <typename T>
void increment(T* x)
{
    std::cout << "Argument type is : " << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
    //x = x + 1;
}  

int main()
{
    const int x = 0;
    const int y = x;
    increment(x);
    increment(&y);
}
```

Output:

```
Argument type is : int 
Argument type is : int const *
```

Please, can you explain why `const` is not shown with reference?

Comment: Because `const` is a qualifier, not a type?

Comment: why then it is showing this qualifier for pointer arguments ?

Comment: Try printing : `typeid(int const).name()`.

Comment: ... and try printing `typeid(int const*).name()` and `typeid(int * const).name()` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`typeid` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

> If type is a reference type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the referenced type.

and

> In all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid (that is, `typeid(T)==typeid(const T)`)

(more precisely top-level `const`) `T` was of course deduced as `const int`.

---

<sup>The standard paragraphs are `[expr.typeid]/4` and `[expr.typeid]/5`</sup>

Comment: So is there any way to know that T is deduced as const int

Comment: @Kapil Because that is not the top level `const`. You can check the `const`-ness with `std::is_const` trait.

Comment: @Kapil for checking types use Scott Mayers trick: `template<typename T> struct TD; TD<T> ii;` or `template<typename T> struct TD; TD<decltype(variable)> ii;` this generated compilation error which contains also exact type of `T` type or `variable`

Comment: @Kapil, there are plenty of ways to know if T is deduced as const int, just not `typeid`

Answer (score 4):

**C++11 §5.2.8/4**

> **”** … If the type of the *type-id* is a reference to a possibly *cv*-qualified type, the result of the `typeid` expression refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the *cv*-unqualified referenced type. …

**C++11 §5.2.8/5**

> **”** The top-level *cv*-qualifiers of the glvalue expression or the *type-id* that is the operand of `typeid` are always ignored.

Essentially, any top-level `const` is dropped, just as with formal function argument types wrt. the resulting function type, and additionally the *cv* qualification of `T` in a reference type `T&`, is dropped.

The latter is possibly in order to not make a distinction between `T&` and just `T` – they yield the same result.

Comment: So basically in this case, *const dropping* is two steps process.

Comment: @Nawaz: I think the simplest conceptual model and what the rules are designed to model is a two step transformation, yes. Remove reference-to, then remove any *cv*-qualification of that result. But formally the case at hand is just one step, via §5.2.8/4.